# Throwing a basketball. What do I need to consider to hit a target?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics, projectile

This is a question that's been bugging me for some time now and the physics department at school is closed so yeah. Anywho, my question was, given a ball of mass .76, what forces would i have to consider so that when i throw the ball from a distance of say 5meters away it hits the center of the rim that is 3.048M high? i know kinematic equations but there are other things to consider to like mass, air drag etc.

and also, how should i throw the ball so that at its peak, it descends towards the rim at a 45 degree angle

Comment: Can you solve second-order differential equations? Specifically, of the form $\ddot{x}=-g-k\dot{x}$?

Comment: Hi _how should i throw the ball so that at its peak, it descends towards the rim at a 45 degree angle_  imo if you can assume a parabola/hyperbola shape, that's a lot more like real life than a "sharp" 45 degree angle , and much easier to model.  open to correction on this tho.  regards

Answer (score 1):

It's a very strange question. In theory a ball is thrown in the shape of a parabola. You can get the graph of the thrown ball with this equation:

$$y=\frac{-gx^2}{2V^2 \cos^2 (a)} + x\tan a$$

where $a$ is the angle at which the ball is thrown, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration, and $V$ is the initial velocity. If you want to calculate the initial force, just multiply the velocity by mass to calculate the momentum, and then figure out the force that is needed. Choose somewhere as the $O=(0,0)$ of your graph, get the $x$ and $y$ of your ball's starting place and the basket, put them in the formula and solve for $V$ and $a$. $g$ is about 9.8.

But about the air drag? It's not that easy. It requires some hard calculations, and it depends on so many factors, like your ball's diameter and the pressure and temperature. and it requires lots of measurements. It is not that easy.

The other thing is, imagine you know the force: how do you know how to apply it? Do you have a force measurement device on your muscles? It's only fun to think about that; it can not be that practical. And the equation above is only gives us a reasonable answer if the ball is very small.

And one last thing: you can not determine the angle beforehand; it may or may not give you an answer. You have to calculate your angle, too. Maybe your have to throw at an angle of 37 degrees in order for your ball to go to the basket.